# any wordpress plugin to make a Supervisor on custom category

Tags: wordpress

any wordpress plugin to make a Supervisor on custom category to mange posts and comments add , edit or delete on this category only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

[image: Restrict Author Posting]

> This is particularly useful if you have an author specific column on
> your site. Perhaps something like Dear Abby, or maybe you want to only
> allow certain authors to write in the Tech Category.
> [Download Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-author-posting) | [Usage](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-authors-specific-category-in-wordpress/)